# Create a UserControl from a Model - Share ViewModel Property between UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have created an UserControl that encapsulate two UserControl.
The first one is a "model" that can be changed by the User. It represents a ObservableCollection of TextBox. Each one of them is filled by the User.

My second UserControl will be a List of UserControl.
Each sub UserControl will be a list of textbox.
I want to be able to create my second UserControl by using the information of the first UserControl ==> Text in each Textbox used in tooltip of textbox.

So what I want is when the user add a field in the first usercontrol to be able to add the same field in each item of my second UserControl.

The black rectangle represents my model and the red rectangle represents my second usercontrol so the use of my model to create a UserControl.
[image: Preview]

Each UserControl owns his ViewModel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please try the next architecture:

1. First User Control observable collection. The ObservableCollection supports event which will be raised when item will be added/deleted/etc. Submit on this event in your first user control view model.
2. Second User control let its view model be composed of ObservableCollections.
3. Share the EventAggregator (link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx)) between view models of your controls. First user control view model will be publisher and the second will be subscriber.
4. Each time when the observable collection of the first user control view model will be changed, publish the aggregator event to inform about the fact that this collection was changed.
5. Second user control will get the event and perform action (add/delete) on all its collection.

**update**

You can manage the sharing mechanism so that the EventAggregator will be the same reference, but the published object will have a key which represents a particular tab (for example the hash code of the tab), thus each subscriber will know if it have to response or not.

That's all. Try to perform that, I'll be glad to help if you will problems with the code.

Regards.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for you response. I thought of this pattern but I need to create First UserControl and SecondUsercontrol in multiple Tab. And each tab need to be independent. I thought it will raise some issue because each tab need to have its EventAggregator pattern, no ?